# Does an AC Diode Chain require cross-links?

Tags: diodes, ac

I found an example of reducing AC voltage by using a double diode chain (on a train modelling site) but it shows each pair of reversed diodes cross-linked as well as connecting to the next pair in line. Are the cross links necessary? (first picture)

I would have thought just the two chains would work correctly (second picture).
Are there any pros or cons in these two options?

[image: With cross-Links]

[image: No cross-links]

Comment: It's a statistical thing to cross link them. A better solution is to add capacitors across each diode pair.

Comment: by the way, reducing your peak-to-peak voltage by 5.6 V using diodes is interesting, and makes sense if you want to avoid a second transformer and have only small currents. However, it also leads to distortion – when the "original" AC voltage drops to between -2.8 and +2.8 V, much less current can flow. This might or might not be a problem for your application! Mind telling us what that application is?

Comment: To see what I'm talking about: http://tinyurl.com/ykgok9k4

Comment: Marcus, it is for my own model train controller(circa mid 2000s). It outputs 18.5 VAC for accessories but my vintage N gauge train accessories were designed for 16 VAC and most model train sites warn against over-driving the older items because they have seen damage in some situations.

I was hoping to avoid current loss by using diodes. The total output of the controller is 20VA including the DC output for the train and the AC output for accessories, so the AC output will be under 1 Amp.

Comment: Andy, can you tell me what the capacitors will do rather than the cross-links? (...and obviously they would be non-polarised capacitors).

Marcus- by the way- nice demonstration.

Comment: Oh, Marcus, by the way, the accessories I am talking about would be a small motor in a turntable, point solenoids, track and building lighting and tiny incandescent bulbs in the track control switches.

Comment: Hmmm turntable? If it's for displaying purposes, this will be totally fine, but I hear people who are into high quality LP repro say that unlike a lot of the audiophile nonsense you *don't* hear (like whether your sound card runs at 44.1 kHz or 96 kHz, or whether your connectors are gold-plated), jittering LP drives is something that is audible, if not mitigated by mass histeresis (which seemingly doesn't take very much mass)

Comment: Ah, no, not a music turntable; a model railway turntable. It rotates the locomotive to different tracks. So my accessories are not speed/frequency sensitive.

Comment: I sort of have an answer now but I am still interested in learning about Andy's suggestion to add capacitors across the diode pairs instead of links. 

Can anyone tell me what the capacitors would do rather than the cross-links?